bending beams with holes

I am trying to bend a cantilever beam with a hole in the middle, but every time I tried to do it did not bend correctly. Could you help me with this?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Hello, what method are you using? Maybe try with a Curve modifier?

Hello, I am using simple  deform

Have you tried with a Curve modifier, also, are the 2 objects supposed to bend together or one after the other?

I have tried but I could not get the smooth results again. The bottom cantilever works well, I just want that black one with holes bend as a whole. Btw, yes I want them to bend simultaneously. Thank you so much for your help.

could you please share your file so that we can give a try?

Did you apply your scales (ctrl+a)?

@moonboots, of course I can attach. 

@DanielMöller, I belive I tried but it did not change anything

Create this kind of curve:

Give your objects a Curve modifier with this curve as Curve Object and with the correct axis (here -Y):

Move the curve in order to bend the objects:

File: 

Thank you so so much. If it is not too much, could you share with me the updated file ?

Sure, see my edit
